# How to express this TOML format in Serde

Tags: rust, serde, toml

I have a Rust structure that I can deserialize:

```
pub struct ProcessReference {
    pub alias: Name,
    pub source: String,
    #[serde(rename = "input")]
    pub initializations: Option<HashMap<String, JsonValue>>,
}
```

where `input` is optional. This accepts TOML formats:

```
[[process]]
alias = "other"
source = "other.toml"
```

or

```
[[process]]
alias = "other"
source = "other.toml"
input.input1 = 1
```

I would like to have the `input` be extendable with a second value, not just the `JsonValue`, so that this could also be deserialized:

```
[[process]]
alias = "other"
source = "other.toml"
input.input1 = {1, true}
```

similar to that used by Cargo for dependencies:

```
[dependencies]
flowrlib = { path = "../flowrlib", version = "~0.7.0" }
yaml-rust = "~0.3.5"
```

How can I express that in Serde?

Comment: See also [How to use Serde to parse a YAML file with multiple different types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55245914/155423)

Comment: Exactly what Rust type do you expect `{1, true}` to deserialize to? It doesn't even appear to be valid TOML.

Comment: No, it's probably not. I wanted to basically supply either a value (is a json value in fact) or a value and a boolean... Arrays can be mixed. I eventually had to work around it using an untagged enum which ended up more verbose than I wanted, but it works.